# Application build fails after migrating library build to Gradle 4.5.1

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have an application that uses library A that was converted to build with Gradle 4.5.1 (from 3.5.1). Library A in turn depends on library B that was also converted to use Gradle 4.5.1.

The application build now fails when attempting to build with library A (it does not directly include a dependency to library B). The build error is a resource not found error against resources from library B.

application:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('com.example:libraryA:version@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

library A:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.example:libraryB:version@aar'
}
```

If I directly include library B in the dependencies of the application, then the build works, however I don't want to do that because I don't want to specify the dependencies of library A in the application and I don't want to have to keep updating the version of library B as the version used by A is incremented.

It also builds if I use the `compile` directive instead of `implementation`, however, I don't want to do that because `compile` is going to be obsoleted. Also, using `api` doesn't appear to address the problem.

How can I get the build to work without needing to specify the dependencies of library A?

Comment: Have you tried not using trasitivie at all? meaning:
`dependencies {
    implementation('com.example:libraryA:version@aar')
}`

Comment: @tomer.z I just tested and removing `transitive=true` doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use `api` instead of `implementation`:

`api('com.example:libraryA:version@aar')`

Comment: If I do that I still get resource not found errors.

Comment: how does library a refer to library b?

Comment: make sure library A refers to library B using `api` as well

Comment: Even when using api in both places I get the resource not found error.

Comment: This is slightly wrong. You want library A to also expose resources from library B. That means you should use `api('com.example:libraryB:version@aar')` in your library A. In your application use `implementation`. The application is the end of the line, it cannot be depended upon by other modules.

Comment: @EugenPechanec this doesn't work for me. When I use `implementation` in my app and `api` in library A, I get the resource not found errors (at compile time) when I build my app.

Comment: @ThomasW are you sure that the resources you're trying to use in the app are defined in library B and not any of its own dependencies?

Comment: @EugenPechanec Yes, the resources that are the source of the errors are in library B.